# Stripe Search PaymentIntent API

Tags: java, spring-boot, stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

Just a small doubt in PaymentIntent API of stripe,
Can we search any Payment intent based on metaData whose value pair is list.

For ex:
I have this metaData:
order_id: 6735 and
amount: [12,78,45]

And below is the code:

```
PaymentIntentSearchParams params =
  PaymentIntentSearchParams
    .builder()
    .setQuery("status:'succeeded' AND metadata['order_id']:'6735'")
    .build();

PaymentIntentSearchResult result = PaymentIntent.search(params);
```

Now I have to search based on the criteria whose order_id is 6735 and amount is 78?
How can I achieve this through PaymentIntent search API?

Comment: This may help you: https://stripe.com/docs/search#query-fields-for-payment-intents

Answer (score -1):

Stripe Metadata[1] are a set of key-value pairs, where values are up to 500 characters long. You can store only primitives type values. You can’t store an Array in Metadata.

Even when you store the Array as a String in metadata (ex: metadata[list]:”[1, 2, 3]”) you can’t search using the substring match operator `~` [2] because metadata are stored as Tokens, which mean you can only do exact match queries (case insensitive)[3].

In the meanwhile, here are the query fields for the PaymentIntent [4], for example if you want to search for the amount in the PaymentIntent, you can query it directly: `amount>1000'`.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata

[2] [https://stripe.com/docs/search#search-syntax:~:text=Substring%20match%20operator](https://stripe.com/docs/search#search-syntax:%7E:text=Substring%20match%20operator)

[3] [https://stripe.com/docs/search#field-types,-substring-matching,-and-numeric-comparators:~:text=exact%20match%20(case%20insensitive)](https://stripe.com/docs/search#field-types,-substring-matching,-and-numeric-comparators:%7E:text=exact%20match%20(case%20insensitive))

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/search#query-fields-for-payment-intents